# New Android Studio IDE not supported in Linux?

Tags: android-studio

I have Ubuntu 16.04.1 on my machine and my system meets all the requirements given in the Android Studio home page. My system information and the Android Studio installation page as seen from my browser are given in the links given below
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/p32mU.png]
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ZmS1.png]
Before this I had elementary 0.4 installed on my system which showed the same error. Should I try installing Ubuntu 12.04 or am I missing something else?
My system information:

```
Architecture:          x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:            Little Endian
CPU(s):                4
On-line CPU(s) list:   0-3
Thread(s) per core:    2
Core(s) per socket:    2
Socket(s):             1
NUMA node(s):          1
Vendor ID:             GenuineIntel
CPU family:            6
Model:                 69
Model name:            Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-4010U CPU @ 1.70GHz
Stepping:              1
CPU MHz:               902.792
CPU max MHz:           1700.0000
CPU min MHz:           800.0000
BogoMIPS:              3392.13
Virtualization:        VT-x
L1d cache:             32K
L1i cache:             32K
L2 cache:              256K
L3 cache:              3072K
NUMA node0 CPU(s):     0-3
```

and the message in my browser says, YOUR OPERATING SYSTEM IS NOT SUPPORTED see the requirements.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Please, provide text outputs rather than screenshots. It helps finding the question and improves formatting. Thanks

Comment: I can't get to the error message in your image.  Will you click th elink that says, "Your OPerating Sysem is Not supported / See the Requirements".  I would like to read the text under there.  By the way, it'll be much easier to read if you edit your message and add the text from the page, rather than an image of the text.

Comment: You have an answer provided by Edwinski.  Does that work?  Your image shows something to click on to see the requirements.  Can you click on that, and paste the requirements response they are presenting to you?

Comment: @L.D.James It seems to be a Firefox problem. Were you able to reproduce what I wrote?

Comment: @edwinksl Yes.  Neither Chrome or Chromium, or Opera produces the error response.  Only Firefox.  On one of my machines I have a Firefox PPA that works.  But one if the repository produces the error the OP is seeing.  I guess Firefox eventually fixes that particular glitch.  But I already upvoted your resolution that works.

Comment: @L.D.James The Firefox I tested with is from the Firefox Beta PPA and that didn't work for Android Studio.

Comment: @edwinksl Thanks for correcting me... you're absolutely right.  I must have tested one of the other browsers twice.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The problem here is **not** related to your operating system, so the "YOUR OPERATING SYSTEM IS NOT SUPPORTED" error message is **completely misleading**.

This seems to be only a problem in Firefox but not in Chromium and Chrome. I was able to download Android Studio in Chromium and Chrome but not Firefox. The easiest solution is to use Chromium or Chrome.

This problem has been reported before in [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36332712/unable-to-download-android-studio) and the solution suggested there is to use Chrome.

Alternatively, the URL for downloading the latest version of Android Studio as of writing is https://dl.google.com/dl/android/studio/ide-zips/2.2.0.12/android-studio-ide-145.3276617-linux.zip. So, open a terminal using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>  and then download the `.zip` file:

```
wget https://dl.google.com/dl/android/studio/ide-zips/2.2.0.12/android-studio-ide-145.3276617-linux.zip
```

Then, follow the installation instructions at https://developer.android.com/studio/install.html to install Android Studio.

Update: It looks like the Android Studio [website](https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html) has been fixed for some Firefox users and I can now see the download button in my own Firefox (version 49.0). I would like to think this question has brought attention to what I perceive as a discriminatory practice by Google/Android.

Comment: Thank you for providing the link. I am currently installing chrome to see if it is a glitch in firefox.

Comment: @paulthomas No problem. If you do see what I saw, then I think you (and I too) should file a bug report somewhere (not sure where yet) and make sure the website maintainers are aware of this problem, especially when the error message is absolutely misleading because the OS is not the problem _at all_.

Comment: The link is actually working in Chrome. And it's not just about mis-information. The downloading link itself is broken and there are no visible troubleshooting options too. Personally, I was thinking about error reporting to Firefox.

Comment: @paulthomas Yeah, good point, it could be a problem on Firefox's end but I am leaning towards Google/Android somehow deliberately not allowing Firefox to download Android Studio...

Comment: Tested on FF 47, Same here. Are you suspecting evils done by Google?

Comment: @Anwar Yup :( I will go make some noise about this later. :)

Comment: The page has this to determine the OS being used: `if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("Linux")!=-1 && navigator.appVersion.indexOf("Android")==-1) {
    os = "Linux";
    bundlename = '#linux-bundle';
    $toolslink = $('#linux-tools');
  }`

Meanwhile, in Firefox's console:
`06:30:21.315 <-- navigator.appVersion
06:30:21.362 --> "5.0 (X11)"`

Yes, this is definitely Google locking you in to using Chrome to download Android Studio.

Comment: @A.Wilcox Sounds like incompetence/unwillingness to follow web standards on the part of the developers, given appVersion is a deprecated property.

Comment: @paulthomas It appears that the page now works for Firefox! I am not sure what happened but it looks like Google/Android fixed the page.

Comment: Still is present the "bug" for Firefox, I cant see the green download button.. only in Chromium

Comment: @mlacunza Hmm, okay, so I guess not all Firefox users can see it yet...

Answer (score 2):

I recommend to use official `Android` page, section `Tools` to download directly newest Android Studio: http://tools.android.com/download/studio/builds/android-studio-2-2-stable

Direct link (Linux): https://dl.google.com/dl/android/studio/ide-zips/2.2.0.12/android-studio-ide-145.3276617-linux.zip

I'm already using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS with Chrome, so as someone said this might be problem with web browser not system

Hope it will help